# Carcassonne fairy - scoring with a fairy for multiple areas and at the end

Tags: carcassonne

Here are the more in-depth rules for The Princess and The Dragon expansion:
http://www.modernjive.com/carcassonne/carcassonnefaq.htm

But it does not answer my questions (I assume the fairy protects a **tile**, not a follower):

1. Does the fairy score at the end of the game? Meaning: If i have a fairy on a tile containing **my** unfinished castle, **friend's and my** unfinished road and, say, two different farms which both belong to **me**, do I get 3 points for "scoring" a castle even though it is not finished, because one of its tiles contain a fairy, 3 bonus points for the unfinished road, with the same explanation as the castle (also 3 points for my friend) and 6 points for 2 farms containing the tile with a fairy? **To simplify, does a fairy grant a bonus at the end of the game for the farms and/or unfinished objects (that are actually "scored")?**
2. Can one player score multiple finised objects with one fairy? E.g. by placing a tile with a road and a castle (**both mine**) which finishes them both and immediately putting a fairy there grants me 3+3=6 bonus boints? Or does one get the bonus only once, no matter how many objects he owns on that particular fairy-occupied tile?
3. If my monastry neighbors a tile with a fairy and the monastry gets surrounded completely, thus scored, do I get the bonus 3 points or does the fairy have to be on the monastry tile itself?

Comment: Off-topic - is The Princess And The Dragon worth getting?!

Comment: From what I've played (multiple times), so "Princess and Dragon", "Traders and Builders", "Inns & Cathedrals", "River" and "Hills & Sheep" it is the only one that allows players to collect their followers (or, more often, send back the other players' followers), introducing the ever-living strategy of all-versus-one. That means everyone wants to harm the strongest player. I like it this way. The magic portal is a nice touch as well, allowing you to call dibbs on some unreachable zones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the rules:

> When a feature (city, road, cloister, or farm) with the fairy is scored, the player whose follower stands on the tile with the fairy scores 3 points for standing there, and may score for the feature as normal. When scored, the follower returns to its owner, but the fairy remains.

Make special note of "When scored, the follower returns to its owner, but the fairy remains."
This means that you can only get the 3 bonus points by scoring something which will remove your follower from the tile. This can lead to multiple bonuses. The fairy is placed at the time you would place a follower, which comes before scoring (this should answer number 2).

As for the monastery, once again the rules state that you should return your meeple, and I don't see that happening with the monastery being finished (unless another feature is finished along the way).

Comment: And specifically " follower stands on the tile with the fairy", so you'd need two meeples on the tile with the fairy to get the two bonuses.

Comment: @user2352164 Excuse me, by monastery I meant the cloister. I have a Polish version. As far as I know, you return a meeple from the cloister when you surround it with tiles. How does it work then?

Comment: Plus, the main point: the question (point 1) is somewhat of philosophical nature: at the end of the game, when no more tiles can be drawn, the players are scoring for the unfinished roads, castles and cloisters and for the farms. From what you said I think that a farmer **can** gather bonus three points **if and only if** he supplies a city (?? because otherwise he "scores" nothing). But we also "score" for the unfinished areas and kinda "remove" the meeples accordingly. That confuses me, while I do not know if I should grant the bonus 3 points for the cities or not.

Answer (score 2):

> When a feature (city, road, cloister, or farm) with the fairy is scored, the player **whose follower stands on the tile** with the fairy scores 3 points for standing there, and may score for the feature as normal. When scored, the follower returns to its owner, but the fairy remains.

The important part is the only meeple to get the bonus have to be on the SAME TILE as the fairy.  And while there are 2 ways with expansions I am aware of that allow multiple meeple on a **single tile**, that is the only way you will get multiple bonuses.